# Photoshop; Export New Document Presets

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As most Photoshop users have have probably noticed, when creating a new document you have the ability to save the new document settings as a preset for later use.

I have a few dozen of these presets, which I want to share with other people (without having to have them manually create each one).

Except I've had no success in finding where Adobe has decided to store these presets. Hence my question, does anyone know how I can export my new document presets for distribution to other Photoshop users?

I have CS4, but the question applies to other versions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mac OS X:**

```
<User>/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS4/Presets
```

**Windows XP:**

```
[Drive]:\Document and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS4\Presets.
```

**Windows Vista:**

```
[Drive]:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS4\Presets
```

If you're using Windows, the files are probably hidden so you need to make sure that you enable "Show hidden files and folders" (you can do this in the Control Panel > Folder Options> "View" tab).

Comment: Turns out its actually; `[Drive]:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS4\Adobe Photoshop CS4 Settings\New Doc Sizes.psp`. Wouldn't have found it without your direction, cheers.

Comment: I found this file **Default New Doc Sizes.txt** at **Adobe Photoshop CS5\Locales\en_US\Support Files** and nothing in the 2 locations you mentioned. That file contains only the original ones and nothing that I created?
Any other solution? I'm using CS5

Comment: Me too, can't find it just the one inside Locales. help!! CS6 here

Comment: [John Shammas just found it](http://forrst.com/posts/Photoshop_CS6_Import_Export_new_Document_Prese-2G3#comment-612273) :)  the correct location on MacOSX is `~/Library/Preferences/Adobe Photoshop CS6 Settings/New Doc Sizes.psp`

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 (Adobe Photoshop CC 2018):

```
%APPDATA%\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2018\Adobe Photoshop CC 2018 Settings\
```

File: **New Doc Sizes.json**

*The path will depend on the installed version of your Adobe Photoshop.*

You can even edit the contents of the JSON file, but obviously it is recommended that any manipulation in the file be done only with Photoshop closed, and respecting the JSON syntax / File Structure. Whereas too that version of PS don't allow edit the preset of new document using the GUI, like rename.

Comment: Based on the date of the question, you can reasonably assume the question is not about Windows 10. Also, the question notes Photoshop version CS4, not CC 2018.  While your information may be helpful to people with newer PS versions, it does not actually answer the question that has been asked.

Comment: oh no, really? Wow.

Comment: UPDATED - Photoshop CC 2020 ( v21.2.1)

1. File is: New Doc Sizes.json

C:\Users\(user name)\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2020\Adobe Photoshop 2020 Settings\New Doc Sizes.json

2. If you created/saved a new preset in Photoshop, you must close Photoshop in order for the preset to be saved to disk. So, close/re-run Photoshop in order to flush any new presets to disk then you can see/edit the .json file in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a file named `New Doc Sizes.psp` which contains your created new document presets.  Path for Windows 7 (64-bit) and Adobe Photoshop CS6:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6\Adobe Photoshop CS6 Settings
```

Comment: What can the user do with this file?  Can he just give his copy of the file to other people and have them install it in the same location in their directory?  What if they already have document settings of their own?  Can the files be merged?  What format is the file in?