# Photoshop CS6, Export New Document Presets

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

Does anyone know how I can export my new document presets for distribution and backup?

The previous CS4 answer does not correlate to CS6 as the specific presets are not in the folder specified.

[image: These presets]

The above presets are not in

```
<User>/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS4/Presets
```

As all those folders are empty

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photoshop CS4, Export New Document Presets](http://superuser.com/questions/86367/photoshop-cs4-export-new-document-presets)

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely what you need:

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/preset-migration-photoshop-cs6.html

and a more readable one

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/979607

P.S. Adobe's help links don't rot. Maybe they will in 10 years when this question is irrelevant.

```
Manually import presets

To manually import presets from previous versions into Photoshop CS6, do the following:

    Choose Edit > Presets > Export/Import Presets.
    Select Import Presets.
    Select the presets you want to import, or click Add All.
    If you saved your presets to a folder that is not the default, select Select Import Folder, and choose the appropriate folder.
    Click Import Presets.

Note: In Step 3, you can choose Select Import Folder, and choose your Photoshop CS5 preset folder.
```

etc...

```
PRESET FILE LOCATIONS:

(Note that there are two different folder locations for presets, one for application provided default presets, and one for user created preset files)



These are the presets that are unique to each user on the computer. These can be migrated automatically: (this is the location that the user should save their personal presets in)




Windows:  Users/[user name]/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS6/Presets



Mac:  Users/[Username]/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS6/Presets





These are the default presets that ship with Photoshop.  These presets can be imported but will not copy over using the migrate feature because each version of Photoshop will install defaults for that version.


Windows 64 bit: 

    [Hard Drive]:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Presets



WindowsXP and Windows7 32 bit:

      [Hard Drive]:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6\Presets



Mac:

    [Hard Drive]/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS6/Presets
```

Comment: Hi!  Link-only answers are a no-no due to possible future link-rot.  Please include the pertinent information directly in your answer(s), and cite the sites as sources.

Comment: Adobe's help links don't rot. Maybe they will in 10 years when this question is irrelevant. But not like i mind excerpts.

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have also mentioned that we're trying to build a stand-alone repository of questions and answers, not a collection of links to other sites -- that's what Google is for. ;)